# How to install composer and npm on godaddy shared hosting for real time application

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I have already asked with the godaddy support with regards to this but they have different answers. Some says that godaddy shared hosting can install node js and composer, but others say no and advised me to purchase a VPS.

I am very much confused. I also checked on some other sites but there are also different answers.

Perhaps, people from stackoverflow can give me exact and reliable resources which can give me an answer to this question.

I don't want to purchase a hosting if I am not sure with the package.

By the way, **I am using Laravel 5.4 with real time application** and it needs to have a composer and node js (npm)  installed to work this real time feature. I tried it and it's working on my local xampp. I am not sure if it does on godaddy shared hosting.

Does anybody know?

Comment: I believe this to be more of a hosting company related issue. The hosting company should give you the correct answer

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you. but, even the agents I talked with have different answers as stated on my question.

Comment: To make sure I haven't misunderstood you... You are stating that your app needs to install and uninstall libraries as part of its routine, aren't you? Do you have SSH access as part of your plan?

Comment: This is the godaddy link to ssh into your shared account [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-your-server-or-shared-hosting-account-with-ssh-4943)

Comment: try `apt-get install composer` but you must have ssh access

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you purchase some cloud server platform that gives you more control on what you can install, maybe go with digital ocean they have good tiers.

Comment: thanks. but let me know the amount compared to deluxe?

Comment: you can get as low as 5$ per month, then upgrade as your application expands.

Comment: and the best part is you have more control of the server to use composer and npm efficiently in your projects.

Comment: pretty good then. do you have the link? is it on godaddy hosting?

Comment: no the hosting itself is within, ever heard of cloud servers? Its just an example.